# wp_nav_menu inside an object -- how do I deal with fallback_cb?

Tags: menus, oop

I'm trying to create a class that allows me to generate a navigation menu.  Here's a simplified version of what I'm using:

```
class PJ_Menu {
    function make_menu() {
        $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'location',
            'fallback_cb' => array( $this, 'pj_page_menu' ),
        );
        wp_nav_menu( $args );
    }
    function pj_page_menu() {
        // a bunch of code here
    }

}
new PJ_Menu();
```

I can't seem to work out what I need in the `fallback_cb` parameter.  `array( $this, 'pj_page_menu' );` didn't work, and neither did `'self::pj_page_menu'`.  Am I missing something obvious, or is it not possible to do this?

Comment: Is your class static?

Comment: Sure?  (I'm far from expert in object-oriented programming.) At the end of the day I declare `new PJ_Menu();` and call it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fallback_cb` argument is used when the menu doesn't exist-- that is, when there is no menu of the right name. I won't be used otherwise. [Check the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). By default the fallback is `wp_page_menu`.

Your code looks right to me for using a class method as the callback, but I suspect that what you really want is the `walker` argument, not the `fallback_cb` one. The `walker` argument will be used any time that your menu is created, not just as a fallback if something goes wrong.

Comment: The issue seems to be that `fallback_cb` expects a `string` and I'm trying to hand it an `array`. But you're probably right -- I'm likely abusing the `fallback_cb` concept entirely.

Comment: That is the correct way to use an object method though I have never tried exactly what you are trying. Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors, but when I do `var_dump( $args );` the `fallback_cb` parameter is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_nav_menu` calls PHP's [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func) on `fallback_cb`. To pass in a class method as that argument, the method needs to be static and you need to pass in the class and method name.

```
static function pj_page_menu() {
    // a bunch of code here
}
```

From PHP's [`is_callable`](https://www.php.net/is_callable) documentation, `fallback_cb` should be in the form:

```
'fallback_cb' => array('PJ_Menu', 'pj_page_menu')
```

or for PHP >= 5.2.3

```
`fallback_cb` => 'PJ_Menu::pj_page_menu'
```